# assembly - Ways to specify section

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

Questions are:

- What is the difference between `.section .text` and `.text`, in assembly code, when using `gcc`.
- And, what does `.ascii` mean in `.ascii  "Hello, world\n"`?

Comment: _"what does `.ascii` mean?"_ https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Ascii.html#Ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.text says the next code is to go into the text segment.

section .text is to create a new, unnamed, section under ".text" to put the next code in.

A section is a minimal unit of instructions belonging together (usually a function/symbol) for the purpose of dead code elimination.

Comment: You mean `.section .text` create a sub section under `.text` ?

Comment: .text is a segment. A segment can be divided into sections (with section .text) or kept as a whole (.text)